# Share domain between two services

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, tumblr

A bit of a strange question but we have a blog that we've been running on Tumblr for a long time and managed to build up a fair amount of traffic. We now want to move the main content over to a wordpress post but keep the smaller posts on tumblr.

Effectively we want the http://ourdomain.com to go to the wordpress site unless the url is in the form of http://ourdomain.com/post/* and then it would show the tumblr post

Any ideas how we would go about doing that?

Answer (score 1):

All requests to a hostname (`ourdomain.com`, in this case) will go to *one* server, while everything after it (`/post/*`) will just be the request to *that* server. This means that you can't have two servers under the same hostname… unless you **set up a proxy** on the server.

It's not really practical, but you can set urls starting with `/post/` to be proxied from a Tumblr at different address (e.g. `ourdomain.tumblr.com`). Although, this means that posts will **also** be available on `ourdomain.tumblr.com/post/*`

---

The saner alternative would be to just have a separate Tumblr on a subdomain like `blog.ourdomain.com` and keep the main site on WordPress.

This works because `blog.ourdomain.com` is a different hostname from `ourdomain.com` and therefore it can be pointed to a different server.